# Setting python pandas histogram size

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I'm trying to set size of pandas histogram when saving to a file. I go about this like that:

```
fig = df_analyze.hist();
fig.set_size_inches(16,12)
plt.savefig('hist.png')
```

But this doesn't work. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: In the master branch of pandas on GitHub the [`hist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) method has a `figsize` parameter for this exact feature. This is not present in earlier versions, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting

```
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 16, 12
```

before calling `df_analyze.hist()` does the job. So, the full solution reads:

```
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 16, 12
df_analyze.hist()
plt.savefig('hist.png')
```